# Checkbox selecionada javascript para controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um grupo de checkboxes que são geradas a partir da BD, consequentemente o id delas será diferente. No meu caso são geradas 3 checkboxes:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check@tpEnt.getId()" name="teste" class="checkbox style-0">
<span>@tpEnt.getDescricao()</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
myJSRoutes.controllers.---Controller.addExemplo().ajax({
                            data : {
                                teste: $("input[name=teste] :checked").val() 
                            }
                        });
```

**Controller (Java)**

`System.out.println("Teste: " + form.data().get("teste"));`

*output:* 'ON' (quando uma das 3 checkboxes está selecionada). Eu gostaria de saber como é que do lado do `controller` posso obter o id da `checkbox` selecionada e não saber se uma das três está selecionada.

**Editado:**

Se em vez de:

```
teste: $("input[name=teste] :checked").val()
```

Se puser:

```
 teste: $("input[name=teste]").attr('id')
```

retorna sempre Check1.

Se puser:

```
teste: $("input[name=teste] :checked").attr('id')
```

retorna null

Comment: Todas as suas checkbox tem sempre o mesmo valor do atributo "name"?

Comment: O usuário pode selecionar nenhuma, uma e/ou mais de uma checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Levando em conta que está trabalhando com checkboxes e pode haver mais de uma selecionada, é interresante que envia um array contendo os ids selecionados.

**HTML**

```
<input id="ckUm" data-type="teste" type="checkbox" checked />
<input id="ckDois" data-type="teste" type="checkbox" />
<input id="ckTres" data-type="teste" type="checkbox" checked />
```

**JavaScript**

```
myJSRoutes.controllers.---Controller.addExemplo().ajax({
    data : {
        teste: function () {
                var checkBoxes = $(":input[data-type='teste']:checked");
                var ids = $.map(checkBoxes, function (checkBox, indice) {
                    return $(checkBox).attr("id");
                });
                return ids;
            }()
    }
});
```

Como Java não é o meu forte, acredito que possa fazer algo do genero:
**Java**

```
System.out.println("Teste: " + String.join(", ", form.data().get("teste")));
```

Comment: Desde já agradeço a ajuda. Na parte do ajax, não reconhece o teste: ids, diz: 'ids is not defined'. No entanto se em vez de ids, colocar uma string qualquer por ex. teste: "exemplo" no controller ele reconhece essa String e imprime-a bem!

Comment: Hugo, como disse Java não é o meu forte, então não estou familiarizado com esta chamada ajax, em todo caso tente denovo (acabei de editar).

Comment: Acredito que sim e de qualquer forma agradeço a sua ajuda. Já não dá erro, agora simplesmente o println retorna null. PS: Só é permitida a seleção de uma checkbox. Não sei se este pormenor poderá ajudar

Comment: como apenas uma checkBox pode ser marcada, então o seu exemplo esta OK, você só precisa alterar o seguinte:
data : { teste: $("input[name=teste] :checked").attr("id") }

Comment: Dessa forma continuo a receber null :s Devo estar a falhar nalguma coisa...Obrigado de qualquer coisa pela ajuda

Comment: uma conrreção: $("input[name='teste'] :checked").attr("id")
sem as aspas fica dificil ;D

Comment: Penso que o problema não estará aí. Voltou a retornar null e tenho casos em que faço assim: nome: $("input[name=nome]").val() e passa bem para o controller, tou é com dificuldades com as checkboxes -.-

Comment: tenta inspecionar as checkbox no browser, para ver se o ID está normal.

Comment: Eu estou a ir buscá-as à BD, não sei se se apercebeu disso, como tal o id está: check@test.getId(), mas sim, no browser, para cada check tenho: Check1 Check2 Check3, tá difícil xD

Comment: Retire o espaço antes do ":" em `$("input[name=teste]:checked").attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Tente (sem espaço antes do `:checked`). Ele vai pegar a `id` do box selecionado:

```
<input id="ck1" name="teste" type="checkbox" />
<br>
<input id="ck2" name="teste" type="checkbox" checked />
<br>
<input id="ck3" name="teste" type="checkbox" />

<script>
    myJSRoutes.controllers.---Controller.addExemplo().ajax({
      data : {
        teste: $("input[name=teste]:checked").attr('id')
      }
    });
</script>
```